# Looking for an easier way to use floats in C#

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

For a number of reasons, I have to use floats in my code instead of doubles.  To use a literal in my code, I have to write something like:

```
float f = 0.75F;
```

or the compiler will barf since it treats just "0.75" as a double.  Is there anything I can put in my code or set in Visual Studio that will make it treat a literal like "0.75" as a float without having to append an "F" every time?

Comment: Come on! How many float constants do you have to define? If many, just use Find and Replace for the few times.

Comment: I agree with @leppie. You really should limit literals like that anyway. If you're doing a lot of default assignments, and it's typically the same value, move them into a static internal class somewhere and reference them that way. Also, you can use lower-case f rather than upper-case F to signify a float literal, saving you a shift keystroke. If you care. :)

Comment: I am curious about why anyone would ever use floats instead of doubles. Can you tell us about your "number of reasons"?

Comment: @Eric: out of curiosity; do you know if this was a deliberate move in the design, in order to promote the use of double over float?

Comment: @Eric:  floats take up half as much memory as doubles, and array-processing operations (e.g. multiplying each value in an array by a certain value) are faster on floats (often twice as fast).  These differences are not significant for most software, but they are very significant for a software synthesizer running on a smartphone.

Comment: @Randolpho:  my OCD won't let me use the lower-case f.  :(

Comment: Sounds like a cool application!

Comment: And yes, in most applications you always want either double or decimal, so "float" is not the default. (Frankly, I would have preferred it if decimal were the default, since more people do financial calculations than scientific calculations.)  In many CPUs, all operations are done in double anyway, so floats are not faster, and in most applications, the extra four bytes is not significant.  I can see how on a handheld device neither of those conditions would be met, and it therefore becomes more sensible to use float.

Comment: @Eric: in my benchmark tests (running in Vista on my PC), iterating through an array and multiplying or adding-to each value in the array takes roughly twice as long with a double[] as with a same-length float[].  I changed from double[] to float[] to speed up the Windows Mobile version, but a 2X speed boost on the PC isn't a bad thing either.  (My PC has a 32-bit processor - I would guess this difference would disappear on a 64-bit machine).

Comment: +1 for decimals as the default, unconventional as that would have been.

Comment: The problem is that some frameworks (i won't mention names but think of a game development framework that starts with X and is made by a *large* software company) use float wherever possible so virtually every number has a little F attached to the end. :(

Comment: @RCIX: It's not just XNA. Many, many gaming libraries prefer single-precision floats to doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float comes with an F :-)

Answer (score 14):

No - fortunately, IMO. Literals are treated the same way everywhere.

This is a good thing - imagine some maintenance developer comes and looks at your code in a year's time. He sees "0.75" and thinks "I know C# - that's a double! Hang on, how is it being assigned to a float variable?" Ick.

Is it really so painful to add the "F" everywhere? Do you really have *that* many constants? Could you extract them *as* constant values, so all your "F-suffixed" literals are in the same place.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the original question, I agree; limit your literals and extract them as constants for maximum maintainability.

Comment: It's not slit-my-wrists painful, but it is annoying.  What I'm doing is largely experimental and involves tweaking parameter values and testing the results.  Sometimes there are lots of these in a formula, so there are lots of Fs to forget to add.

Comment: Then use doubles during your tests and switch to floats later.

Comment: Consider reading them from a config file. That makes tweaking the algorithms easier, and you can omit as many f's as you like.

Comment: @peterchen:  I'm not only tweaking the values fed into the algorithms - I'm also tweaking and changing the algorithms themselves.  Feeding them from a config file would be an unnecessary extra step at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

The language interprets floating point precision literals as doubles everywhere. This is not a configurable feature of the compiler - and with good reason.

Configuring how the language interprets you code would lead to problems with both compatibility and the ability of maintenance developers to understand what the code means.

While not advisable generally, you can reduce the pain a little in C# 3 by using:

```
var f = 0.75F;
```

Just be careful, because forgetting the 'F' suffix with this syntax WILL cause the compiler to create a double, not a float.

Comment: This doesn't reduce that pain at all.  I still have to type the F.

Comment: This is one place where I **wouldn't** use the var syntax for just the reason you described.  On the other hand, I would use doubles, not floats...

Comment: Some languages allow redefining how the code is interpreted using macros, like C for example. It was not included in C# because it's not that very useful and it's so easy to make a mess out of it. :)

Comment: The `var` approach feels a bit dangerous here. `float f = 0.75;` will at least cause the compiler to react; feels like a nice safety net.

Comment: @FredrikMörk: If the compiler obeyed the principle that conversions from more specific types to less specific types of comparable domain are widening (i.e. permitted implicitly), while conversions from less specific types to more specific types require a cast, `float f=0.75;` or even `float f=0.1;` would compile without a squawk, but `double f=0.1f;` would squawk absent an explicit typecast (e.g. `double f = (double)0.1f;`.  Unfortunately, Java implemented backward rules, and .net followed suit.

Answer (score 1):

FYI -- you can find all of the compiler options for C# at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx.  If you check there, you'll see that there isn't any option that allows this -- and rightly so for the reasons that @Jon Skeet noted.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to always use

```
var meaning = 1f;
```

because the "var" keyword saves a lot of human interpretation and maintenance time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really saves any human interpretation - forcing me to look at the end (the f) for the type instead of allowing me to rely on the normal c# convention of having the type be first leaves more room for error and takes longer imo.

Answer (score 0):

The proper behavior would not be for a compiler to interpret non-suffixed literals as single-precision floats, but rather to recognize that conversions from double to float should be regarded as widening conversions since, for every `double` value, there is either precisely one unambiguously-correct `float` representation, or (in a few rare edge cases) there will be precisely two equally-good values, neither of which will be more than a part per quadrillion from being the unambiguously-correct value.  Semantically, conversions from `float` to `double` should be regarded as narrowing conversions (since they require that the compiler "guess" at information it doesn't have), but the practical difficulties that would cause might justify making conversions in that direction 'widening'.

Perhaps one should petition Microsoft to add a widening conversion from `double` to `float`?  There's no good reason why code which calculates graphics coordinates as `double` should be cluttered with typecasts when calling drawing functions.